# How do I upgrade the Android NDK on a Linux machine?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there an automated way to upgrade the Android NDK? Or will I have to replace the older version with the newer one manually after downloading it?

Comment: I don't believe there's an automated way, but what you need to do to "replace" it depends on how you have referenced it.  You can simply unpack the archive beside the other, but if you have explicit references in project build systems or IDE's (or your shell startup) to the path of the older version you will have to update those, or redirect them to the new one with a symbolic link.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks. I simply downloaded the newer version and moved it to the old 'install' place and gave it the same directory name as the old one. It works so far. This process, however, is ugly.